# Google App Engine - query vs. filter clarification

Tags: google-app-engine, datastore

My model:

```
 class User(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Is there any difference in terms of efficiency/cost/speed between the following two queries?

```
 u = User.query(User.name==name).get()

 u = User.query().filter(User.name==name).get()
```

Should I use one of them over the other? I assume the 2nd one is worse because it firsts get the entire User class queryset and then applies the filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in functionality between the two so you can choose whatever you like best.  On the [google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#filter_by_prop), they show these two examples:

```
query = Account.query(Account.userid >= 40, Account.userid < 50)
```

and

```
query1 = Account.query()  # Retrieve all Account entitites
query2 = query1.filter(Account.userid >= 40)  # Filter on userid >= 40
query3 = query2.filter(Account.userid < 50)  # Filter on userid < 50 too
```

and state:

> query3 is equivalent to the query variable from the previous example.

Comment: I know there is no difference in functionality. I just wanted to confirm there is no difference in cost/speed/etc.?

Comment: @JK140, there is not any difference.